# 'int' object is not iterable: TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, sum

I am a newbie and getting this error below. Please advise.

I want to sum all the positive integers(n>0) which are divisible by 3 and 5 without repetition

See my code below:

```
n=100
from collections import OrderedDict

for i in range (-n, n):
  if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
    print(i)
  elif (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 ==0):
    print(i)
  elif i < 0:
    pass
sum(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I do suspect that the error is in ```sum(i)```.  Since ```i``` is an integer,  it is an invalid parameter for ```sum()```.   What exactly did you want to sum?

Comment: ```sum``` function can be used over an iterator only. here ```i``` is an ```int```, so it gives an error when you ```sum(i)```

Comment: I want to sum all the positive integers(n>0) which are divisible by 3 and 5 without repetition

Comment: ```total = sum([i for i in range(-1, n) if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0])```